# How to get the referenced field's name value when the field is referencing multiple types

Tags: soql, rest-api, metadata

I'm using v31.0 of the Salesforce REST API. When looking at the metadata for some of my objects, Salesforce says that the *OwnerId* field references two tables: *Group* and *User*. The JSON that Salesforce returns looks like this:

```
...
referenceTo: [
  "Group",
  "User"
}
....
```

How can I tell which type of object to grab the Name value from? For example, for fields not referencing multiple types, I simply take the referenced object, and put it in a query to find the name value.

```
'select name from ' + referenceTo[0]
```

How can I find out this information when the field is referencing multiple types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can describe each object in referenceTo, and check the keyPrefix attribute against the Id. The key prefix is the first three characters of an Id. I recommend describing all objects that you'll be using and cache those describe results for later use.

Answer (score 1):

If you would rather skip the separate query on the referenced objects, e.g. on `User` or `Group` in the case of `OwnerId`, you can usually safely query on the Name field using relationship syntax, e.g. `Owner.Name`, and Salesforce will fill in a Name field value for whatever type of object is referenced, e.g. the User's name, Group's Name, or, for objects that don't have a field called Name, such as `Solution` and `Case`, Salesforce will take the corresponding Name fields, e.g. `SolutionNumber` and `CaseNumber`, and return those.

For instance, the `Task` and `Event` objects have a `What` field which can point to tons of different standard or custom objects. But you can always query on `What.Name` and expect to get a result. This saves you from having to do a separate SOQL query on the corresponding related object just to get the Name field value:

```
select Subject, ActivityDate, WhatId, What.Name
from Task
where Priority = 'High' 
and IsClosed = false
```

In this query, if the `What` in question is a Case, `What.Name` would return the Case's CaseNumber field, e.g. `00001234`, whereas if the What was an Account, it would return the Account's Name field, e.g. 'Salesforce.com'